# converting list to data frame in R not losing root node

Tags: r, list

Have a list to convert to data frame but I'm losing the root node column:

```
my_list <- list(usdol = list(name = "Dollar", native = "US dollar"), dmk = list(name = "Mark", 
    native = "Deutsch Mark"))


> my_list
$usdol
$usdol$name
[1] "Dollar"

$usdol$native
[1] "US dollar"


$dmk
$dmk$name
[1] "Mark"

$dmk$native
[1] "Deutsch Mark"
```

Converting to data frame this way using qdapTools (list2df)

```
 my_list %>% list2df()

Dollar          usdol           
US dollar       usdol           
Mark             dmk            
Deutsch Mark    dmk
```

Desired outcome is:

```
code  name  secondary_name

usdol Dollar US dollar
dmk    Mark  Deutsch Mark
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option with `unnest_wider` from `tidyr`

```
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
tibble(col = my_list) %>%
      unnest_wider(col) %>%
      mutate(code = names(my_list))%>% 
      select(code, name, secondary_name = native)
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#  code  name   secondary_name
#   <chr> <chr>  <chr>         
#1 usdol Dollar US dollar     
#2 dmk   Mark   Deutsch Mark
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, lapply(my_list, stack), code = names(my_list)))
```